# How can I get a .desktop launcher to use an environment variable?

Tags: linux-mint, environment-variables, cinnamon, desktop-environment, launcher

This is for the program [git-cola](https://github.com/git-cola/git-cola), although I think the question is more general. It is also using LM Cinnamon 18.

The environment variable I want to set is `SCALE_GIT_COLA=2` so that the program looks good with a HiDPI display.

If I add `export SCALE_GIT_COLA=2` to my `.profile`, then open a terminal and run `git-cola`, I get the desired effect.

However, if I use a launcher (I am using [Albert](https://github.com/albertlauncher/albert), but again I think this is more general) to run `git-cola`, then it looks as if `SCALE_GIT_COLA=2` has not been set.

How can I get launchers run through the Cinnamon desktop to respect environment variables set through `.profile`? Or, where else can I add these environment variables so that I get this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

Copy git-cola.desktop file to `~/.local/share/applications/` and modify one line:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/env SCALE_GIT_COLA=2 git-cola
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still launches as if SCALE_GIT_COLA=2 has not been set.

Answer (score 1):

Faced a similar issue on Ubuntu Jammy with Cinnamon desktop. I needed to pass an environment variable from my launcher menu. I found using `env` before the variable allowed it to be passed to the launched program.

Terminator in my case (for fixing double characters on receiver panes) was fixed by adding `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=''` variable. Translating that into a desktop launcher required the following.

Launcher command Before:

```
terminator
```

Launcher command After:

```
env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS='' terminator
```

Hope this proves useful for others in similar cases.